# Distinction between Built-in and Definable Skolem Functions

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

In *A Course on Basic Model Theory* ( Haimanti Sarbadhikari, Shashi Mohan Srivastava, pp. 27-28) and other textbooks, I have found the following distinction:

- A theory T has Built-in Skolem Functions iff $T\models \forall x \exists y \varphi(x,y) \rightarrow \varphi (x,f(x))$
- A theory T has Definable Skolem Functions iff 
  $T \models ∀w∀u∀v ((ψ(w, u) ∧ ψ(w, v)) → u = v),$ 
   $T \models ∀w (∃vφ(w, v) → ∃u (ψ(w, u) ∧ φ(w, u)).$ 
  Moreover, in this latter case we can introduce an anxiom such as: $x=f_{\varphi }(w) \iff \psi (w,u)$

I have few questions about this distinction:
1) Why we have this distinction? 
2) It can be proved that every model has built-in Skolem functions, but not every model has definable Skolem functions. Is that correct? Why so? 
 
3) If point (2) is correct, then having Built-in Skolem functions is enough to prove the equisatisfiability of a first-order formula and its Skolem Normal Form (SNF). Then I would say that, due to the fact that not every model has definable Skolem functions, we cannot prove the logical equivalence between a first-order formula and its SNF. Is this argument sound? Is so, why we need definable Skolem functions to prove the logical equivalence of a first-order formula and its SNF?

Comment: In the first case $f$ is part of the language of $T$ : we have formula $\varphi (x,f(x))$.

Comment: In the second case, having proved the two "functionality" theorems, we may enlarge the language of the adding the finction symbol $f_{\varphi}$ with the corresponding axiom.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Can you please say something more about question n.3? Namely: given that every model has built-in Skolem function, so we can prove the equisatisfiability of a first-order formula and it's Skolem Normal Form (SNF). Yet, given that not every model has a definable Skolem function, we cannot prove the logical equivalence of a first-order formula and it's SNF. Is this argument sound?

Comment: I don’t know what you’re getting at with (2)... surely you don’t mean literally that every model has built-in Skolem functions? Can you say what you mean precisely and why you think it?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}$First let me define better those 2 terms:

$T_\L$ is a Skolem theory(or, has built in Skolem functions, same thing) if:

> For every $n+1$-ary formula $φ$, there exists **in** $\L$ an $n$-ary function symbol $f$ such that $T\models \forall \overline x (\exists y \varphi(\overline x,y) \rightarrow \varphi (\overline x,f(\overline x)))$

That is, the Skolem function is a symbol in the language.

$T_\L$ has definable Skolem functions if:

> For every $n+1$-ary formula $φ$, there exists $n+1$-ary functional relation $ψ$ such that $T\models \forall \overline x (\exists y \varphi(\overline x,y) \rightarrow ∀ z(\psi(\overline x,z)→\phi(\overline x,z)))$.

Now for the questions:

1. We distinguish between the 2 because the fact that there exists a functional relation that behave like the above, does not implies that there exists such symbol $f$. Given that $T_\L$ is Skolem theory, we can simply define $ψ(\overline x, z)=φ(\overline x,z)∧z=f(\overline x)$, I believe you can check that this is indeed a functional relation that satisfy the definition of definable Skolem function. On the other hand, given $ψ$, we can't say anything about the existence of $f$
2. No, take any theory without any function symbols, and you get a theory that is not Skolem theory.

Now, that being said, it is correct that we can just add function symbol for each formula $φ$ and add the axioms $x=f_{\varphi }(w) \iff \psi (w,u)$. The new theory [conservative extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_extension) to the old theory. If the new theory definable Skolem functions again, we can repeat this processes, doing this recursively and we get that the union of all of those is a conservative extension of the original theory and is a Skolem theory.